# Show that the ‖‖$u$+‖‖$v$ vector is perpendicular to the ‖‖$u$−‖‖$v$ vector.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

Show that the ‖‖$u$+‖‖$v$ vector is perpendicular to the ‖‖$u$−‖‖$v$ vector.

What should I do here? If it's perpendicular, the dot product of the two vectors should be 0. But I could not use this.

Comment: What's wrong with using the dot product? Works fine here.

Comment: Why couldn't you use the dot product?  Do you not know how, or did some "authority", like a professor or T.A., forbid it?

Comment: I thought it would be another way because it sounded so simple.

Comment: It pays to actually try the simple thing first before deciding it can't work. Even if it doesn't work you may find out something about the problem by observing *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Next, I'll try it the easiest way (first come to my mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way, if you insist. Recall that $x \perp y$ if and only if $\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$ (the Pythagorean theorem and its converse).

Applying this to $x = \|v\|u+\|u\|v$ and $y = \|v\|u-\|u\|v$, the parallelogram law gives
\begin{align*}
\big\|\|v\|u+\|u\|v\big\|^2 + \big\|\|v\|u-\|u\|v\big\|^2 &= 2(\|\|v\|u\|^2+\|\|u\|v\|^2) \\
&= 4\|u\|^2\|v\|^2 \\
&= \big\|2\|v\|u\big\|^2\\
&=\big\|(\|v\|u+\|u\|v)+(\|v\|u-\|u\|v)\big\|^2
\end{align*}
so $(\|v\|u+\|u\|v) \perp (\|v\|u-\|u\|v)$.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of perpendicular of two vectors $v,u$ is defined to mean $\langle v,u\rangle=0$. So we need to show $\langle ‖‖+‖‖,‖‖−‖‖\rangle=0$, then by definition those two are perpendicular.

Actually,
$$
\begin{eqnarray} \big\langle‖‖+‖‖,‖‖−‖‖\big\rangle&=&‖‖^2\langle ,u\rangle+‖‖‖‖ \langle v,\rangle−‖‖‖v‖\langle u,v\rangle-‖‖^2\langle ,v\rangle\\
&=&0\end{eqnarray}$$ since $‖‖^2=\langle u,u\rangle$ and $‖v‖^2=\langle v,v\rangle$.

let me know if this solves your questions.

Comment: Please use $\langle$ `\langle` and $\rangle$ `\rangle` for angular brackets instead of the *comparison operators* $<$ and $>$. The spacing is all messed up.

Comment: yes it works, thanks buddy!